# Product of two list of different size

Tags: list-manipulation

This has to be very easy, but i can find it.
I have 2 list

`a={8, 15, 12, 1, 13, 21, 14, 4, 15}`

`b={3, 19, 29, 47, 13}`

What I'm trying to do is

`a*b[[1]]*b[[2]]*b[[3]]*b[[4]]*b[[5]]`

It has to be some kind of map but i can’t find it...

Comment: `a (Times @@ b)`?

Comment: Yes! perfect.
2m later...OMG what a dumb question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @J.M. Why **not** close this thread owing to that is a  just a simple issue?

Comment: @Shutao, you can all vote to close if you want; I just don't want to be the only one closing it.